# Group in aggregation including the null values in mongodb

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, php-mongodb

I am trying to group by month and year in an aggregation and return the months that have no data too.

**Example**:
if the period is 01/01/2018 to 01/03/2018 and we search for a rating and rating exists only in February I still want to get January and March with no rating.

```
$pipeline = [
      ['$match'=>[
            'rating'     => ['$exists' => true],
            'date' => [
                              '$gte' => $da->getStart(true),
                              '$lte' => $da->getEnd(true)
                            ],
                  ]
      ],
      ['$project' => [
              'year'  => [
                '$cond' =>  [
                    ['$ifNull' => [$date->appendDollarSing(), 0]],
                    ['$year' =>  $date->appendDollarSing()],
                    -1
                ],
              'month' => [
                '$cond' => [
                    ['$ifNull' => [$date->appendDollarSing(), 0]],
                    ['$month' =>  $date->appendDollarSing()],
                    -1
                ],
              'rating'  => ['$sum'  => '$rating'],
          ]
      ],
      ['$group' => [
                  '_id' => ['year' => '$year', 'month' =>'$month'],
                  'rating'  => ['$sum'  => '$rating'],
                  'count'   => ['$sum'  => 1],
                  ]
            ],
    ];
```

The above query returns the months with rating as I used exists true for the rating. However even if I remove the exists true it does not fetches the months with no rating

Comment: In short It "can" be done, but it's really not worth the effort. More to the point the approach you would have to take is likely to blow up on anything other than a very small result set. This has been asked over and over again and it essentially has the same answer. Just live with adding in the "dates with no totals" that you know fall within the range into the result data "after" you retrieve it from the server. It's not hard to do there, and it's certainly not trivial to ask the server to do this. Let the server do "it's job", which is to return the data which is actually there.